# Results get vary when running spark through local and through yarn?

Tags: pyspark, hadoop-yarn, data-science

```
joined_data_filtered = spark.sql("SELECT T.TransactionId, T.CustomerId, T.StartClusterId, T.EndCentermostClusterId, T.EndClusterId, T.StartCellId, T.EndCellId, T.EndCentermostCellId, T.EndCentermostLatitude, T.EndCentermostLongitude FROM joined_trip_data AS T LEFT JOIN(SELECT CustomerId,StartClusterId,EndClusterId FROM joined_trip_data WHERE EndCellId = StartCellId GROUP BY CustomerId, StartClusterId,EndClusterId) AS D ON T.CustomerId = D.CustomerId AND T.StartClusterId = D.StartClusterId AND T.EndClusterId = D.EndClusterId WHERE D.CustomerId IS NULL")
```

In my pyspark script Initially I cluster the start and end location and then remove the data which have same start and end location. I'm selecting the data with same start and end cellid and get their startclusterid,endclusterid and left join that to the data set and take out the data which are not starting with same start and end with same location.

I ran this query several times through following yarn command and got different results each time.

```
yarn command - spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode client --driver-memory 4g --executor-memory 6g --executor-cores 3 --num-executors 4
```

So I ran two data sets without the join condition and got same count each time.When I'm joining two datasets with startclusterid and endclusterid results get vary. But result is not changing when I run the script through spark-submit --master local[4] command.

I'm using DBSCAN algorithm to cluster start and end latitude,longitude and returning clusterid,Clustercellid.I get different clusterids for a given cluster when I run multiple times through yarn but we think that clusterid doesn't change for a given session.

start cluster for location 'A'   - 1st run through yarn

```
 startcluterid               startcellid

  1                           11126
  1                           11127
```

start cluster for a location  'A' - 2nd run through yarn

```
 startcluterid        startcellid

  5                  11126
  5                  11127
```

Initial Data set before clustering,

```
  TransactionId  CustomerId  StartLat           StartLon           EndLat   EndLon

 17471146           590      41.890334            12.854832        41.91075183          12.86703281
 17540917           590      41.890347            12.854828        41.91041441          12.86689
 18972483           590      41.890389            12.854123        41.91134124           12.86684897
 19037116           590      41.890358            12.854846         41.9107199           12.8671107
 20315292           590      41.8903541           12.85485          41.9107082           12.8672354
 20422794           590      41.890337            12.854812        41.91074152           12.867081
 20458932           590      41.8904              12.854815         41.9107416           12.86717336
 25902100           590      41.890329            12.854836        41.91074148           12.86704109
 29829078           590      41.89034             12.8548             41.91074            12.867
 30024741           590      41.89035             12.8548             41.91078            12.867
```

Can anyone please let me know what's the issue?

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow. Your question is hard to read and could use a lot more formatting - please do so to make it easier for the community to help you.

Comment: I can tell you that using mapPartitions with RDDs could not give 100% correct results in some cases. But that is not the situation here. The YARN command adds no value here. can you provide an explain? You need to provide an example of input, say 10 recs. Interesting question otherwise. I am wondering if under the hood optimization can, like RDDs, produce less than 100% correct results - not sure how, but interested in this scenario for sure.

Comment: How is this  progressing? Are you sure it is still so? Can you send me the code, as I am also interested in this aspect.

Comment: @thebluephantom the issue still there I have share example of input I'm new to pysaprk and rdd I need this script to be run through for optimization purposes

Comment: Ok, later tosay I will look. Very curious.